# Elasticsearch keep writing data into read-only index even when 95% watermark is reached

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a ES cluster with 5 nodes on Kubernetes, each with a 200GB persistent volume. When storage is almost full, I expected elasticsearch will stop writing data into nodes when reached the default watermark (95% of storage) since I did not overwrite the default settings at all.

But currently I found out data node will reached **100% storage**, showing `"stacktrace": ["org.apache.lucene.index.MergePolicy$MergeException: java.io.IOException: No space left on device"` in logs, also causing that data node out of cluster.

Tracing elasticsearch logs, I can see there are messages warning flood stage disk watermark [95%] exceeded, but when time keep going on, the **free size** is getting lower, which means ES is still putting data onto this read-only index and ended up with a 100% full data node, which is really weird and can't find out the reason.

```
Oct 17, 2022 @ 18:35:06.497 {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-10-17T10:35:06,497Z", "level": "WARN", "component": "o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor", "cluster.name": "k8s-logs", "node.name": "es-cluster-4", 
"message": "flood stage disk watermark [95%] exceeded on [uNROMy07QYWfy4dIr6efLw][es-cluster-1][/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0] 
free: 7.2gb[3.6%], all indices on this node will be marked read-only", "cluster.uuid": "T_Fi5-1SSHeMNQymSt87BA", "node.id": "vAKxKXluRCCznUeCDGKzKw"  }

Oct 17, 2022 @ 18:39:06.524 ....  free: 6.6gb[3.3%], all indices on this node will be marked read-only" .... }

Oct 17, 2022 @ 18:48:06.591 ....  free: 5.3gb[2.7%], all indices on this node will be marked read-only" .... }

Oct 17, 2022 @ 19:00:06.715 ....  free: 1.8gb[0.9%], all indices on this node will be marked read-only" .... }
```

This case can be reproduced every time when my ES storage is almost full, even in different ES clusters on different servers.

Comment: Which version are you running?

Comment: Elasticsearch 7.17.2